# urllib.error.URLError when using pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, download

I'm new to Python and trying to download a csv file from the URL below but get an error as below
https://mldata.org/repository/data/download/csv/stockvalues/

**script to download csv which is not working**

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

url = 'https://mldata.org/repository/data/download/csv/stockvalues.csv'

url_data = pd.read_table(url,sep='\t')

url_data.head(3)
```

**Receive the error below**

```
urllib.error.URLError occurred Message=<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
  StackTrace:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:1320 in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:1361 in HTTPSHandler.https_open

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:504 in OpenerDirector._call_chain

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:544 in OpenerDirector._open

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:526 in OpenerDirector.open

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:223 in urlopen

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py:186 in get_filepath_or_buffer

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py:392 in _read

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py:655 in parser_f in _make_parser_function
```

Comment: Just as a bit of a kludge and test - have you tried to see if the http instead of the https version is available?

Comment: @JonClements yes, that was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your url has issues. That error occurs when the url's certificate isn't trusted by your browser. This definitely means there's either something wrong with the site, or something wrong with the link.